# Two people using Google script apps sheet at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to have people register their team for a hotel and then using script apps for that information to clear from the entry sheet and create a new sheet so that each team will have a sheet. I have my code working so that it executes how I want it to, but since there are 100 different teams registering, it's inevitable that there will be more than one person in there at once at some point. Is there anyway to make sure that two clubs can enter information at once without seeing the other teams' data? Or if I could send the teams to a new tab if there is already a team in tab 1? Here is my code:

```
function Copy() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Insert ID here');
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:I3'); 
 var data = range.getValues();
 sss.appendRow(data[0]);
 range.clear();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.create('New Team'); 
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 ts.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); 
}
```

Comment: Possible silly solution would be make font white color of other teams data. I don't know.

Comment: Disclaim it as provisional And it'll be confirmed only after a confirmation email within 24 hours.

Comment: Take a look at using [Google Forms with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms). Just skip over the calendar stuff